# Creating custom confirm popup for CakePHP

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

I'm dealing with editing reservations and adjusting payments based on this. If a reservation is extended, then I need to charge the customer for the extent of this, likewise, if it's shortened I need to refund.

I tried something like this (without actually POSTing anything, just a confirm box), but even when pressed cancel it submitted the form anyway.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('edit',array('onsubmit'=>'return check_dates()')); ?>
//rest of form here

<script>
function check_dates(){
   //make POST request to check previous reservation duration
   if(data.duration == 'longer'){
       confirm('The guest will be charged $X. Click OK to continue');
   }
   if(data.duration == 'shorter'){
       confirm('The guest will be refunded $X. Click OK to continue');
   }
   if(data.duration == 'no_change'){
       confirm('Click OK to continue')
   }
}
</script>
```

Is it possible to do something like this? As I mentioned previously, when I pressed cancel the form submitted anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this live demo: http://jsbin.com/iZididi/2

Here in your check_dates(), you have to set return. if you want the form to submit whatever the answer with confirm just you have replace the last line to be

```
function check_dates(){
     data = new Object();
  data.duration = 'shorter';

  if(data.duration == 'longer'){
       a = confirm('The guest will be charged $X. Click OK to continue');
   }
   if(data.duration == 'shorter'){
       a = confirm('The guest will be refunded $X. Click OK to continue');
   }
   if(data.duration == 'no_change'){
      a = confirm('Click OK to continue')
   }

  //return a;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. That was a lot simpler than I expected. Thanks again!